# NSTableView rebuilds all cells when adding only one

Tags: macos, cocoa, interface-builder, nstableview

I have a view-based `NSTableView` driven by an `NSArrayController` bound to a `NSMutableArray` as the content array.

When I add a new item to the data source, `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` is called for every item in the data source. I would expect the table view to leave existing items alone, and only call this for the new item.

I add a new item via the controller, like this:

```
[_arrayController addObject:newObject];
```

How do I prevent the table view from doing this? The performance impact is unacceptable.

Edit: It also clears the user selection

Comment: This is _unusual_. Does the `-insertObject:atIndex:` method also fail so badly (I’d guess so). I’ve done this before and it worked as I wanted. If you break on `tableView:viewForTableColumn:row:` when this happens what’s the stack look like?